# After install the NuGet package sqlite-net-pcl, JsonSerializer.Serialize raised an exception (Xamarin)

Tags: json, sqlite, xamarin, serialization

To store JSON data, I installed the NuGet package `sqlite-net-pcl` for the  Xamarin project. Before install the package `sqlite-net-pcl`, everything is working normally and I didn't change the contents of code. No ideas what wrong with the setting. Please comment how to solve the problem?

Installed the NuGet package `sqlite-net-pcl` and execute `Serialize`, an exception is raised.

**execute to serialize an object to JSON,**

```
// route is an object 
JsonSerializer.Serialize(route);
```

**and exception is raised unexpectedly.**

```
catch (Exception)
{
  // exception
}
```

Comment: you mean that your project have problem after you install sqlite-net-pcl, there is no problem before?

Comment: fallback to previous version (1.6.292), exception has gone. I didn't test this module in details, but it seems it is stable now.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solve your problem now.